# Can't choose "Tainan City, Taiwan" as my location

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In Stack Overflow Careers, I want to set "Tainan City, Taiwan" as my location.
But it always display the following message: `This location is not specific enough. You must provide at least the city you are currently in.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google currently thinks Tainan City is a state/province, not a city. You'd think the name would be a hint.

Anyway, I've manually overridden this for now so we should accept it as a valid city. Please try again!

Comment: Google? Didn't you use Yahoo services?

Comment: Currently we default to Google and use Yahoo as a fallback.